# Transfer a range of data from excel to oracle using vba

Tags: sql, oracle, vba

I have a requirement.
I have an excel report with 5 sheets  and I want  to send a range of values (for example : values from cell E20:E40) ,( E70: E90 ) )from excel report sheet 3 to my local database table(oracle). Can anybody help to write some code in vba.

Thanks in advance ..
ARUN

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: Put this formula `="INSERT INTO table_name ( column_name ) VALUES ( "&E20&");"` into `F20` and then copy/paste down into `F21:F40` and `F70:F90` (or any empty column) then copy the output of those cells and paste it into your SQL client.

Answer (score 0):

There are many source there, do some self learning first then come with the problem you face.

http://www.encodedna.com/excel/copy-data-from-closed-excel-workbook-without-opening.htm

[Excel VBA connect to remote Oracle DB with InstantClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154288/excel-vba-connect-to-remote-oracle-db-with-instantclient)